# Adding programmatically a control on top of others

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I'm looking for adding a control on top of others controls during runtime.

I read that the only way of playing with the `Z-Order` of controls is by playing with the order of the controls inside the `Form.Controls` Collection. I find this solution very weird and weak and I'm looking for an alternative.

Does anyone has an idea? I just want to make some kind of modal dialog that'll show below another user control to notice the user that the user control is currently doing something.

Edit: I tried using `Control.BringToFront()` but it doesn't work at all.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `BringToFront()` method.

Comment: I tried and it did not worked :S I looked inside the Controls' Collection and my control wasn't at the top at all. Thanks!

Comment: Which control did you bring to front?

Comment: I did the BringToFront() on the control I'm trying to add to the controls. Is it right?

Comment: Yes.  Remember that that's only within its container.

Comment: Its container is where are all the controls from Form.Controls, right?

Comment: Container meaning panels or groupboxes.

Comment: Oh damn, I was using BringToFront() before adding the control into the container... Stupid me. Thanks it is now working fine!!!